# TP-Link TL-WN723N V3 really slow performance on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I've been trying to get my TP-Link USB wireless adapter working on my Dell Inspiron 530 (running 14.04).

According to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link), as of 2015-10-07 it works out of the box on a machine running 14.04 LTS. Also according to that page, it states that the driver that should run the device is the r8188eu driver.

After running a `sudo lshw -C network` command in terminal, the output gives the following:

`configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=xxx.xxx.x.x multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn`

When I plug the device in, Ubuntu immediately recognizes it and connects to my wifi network. However, despite the fact that my router is less than 10 feet away from my computer and is facing the usb wifi dongle, I don't have 0 bars signal strength (occasionally I'll get a blip of 1 bar, which is just enough to take me to a simple web page).

I confirmed that it isn't broken hardware by plugging the dongle into my Windows XP box which is right next to my Ubuntu box. XP registers the dongle and connects to wifi with a connection strength of Excellent.

I was wondering if there is anything that I've overlooked in my efforts to get the USB wifi device to work properly with my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I've read through the 'similar questions' questions recommended to me through the forum, but none of them have proven helpful.

---

Here is the output of `lsusb`. I can see that it is recognizing the device, and it has a code that is very similar to the expected driver, but it is a bit different. The expected driver (according to the website I cite) is R8188EU, but what my machine is showing is RTL8188EUS.

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0644:0200 TEAC Corp. All-In-One Multi-Card Reader CA200/B/S
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c503 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse+Keyboard Receiver
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c501 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci | grep Wireless` (CaSe SeNsItIvE)

Comment: The output of `lspci | grep Wireless` returns nothing. A regular `lspci` returns nothing that looks like it is related to the USB Wifi dongle, but the dongle is currently connected with very weak signal.

Comment: Oops, sorry, made a mistake! Overlooked that it was a USB adapter :P Please run `lsusb`. I'm just trying to find out if the kernel is detecting it correctly.

Comment: I updated my post with your request!

Comment: In doing some research, on the TP-Link website it says that the driver is for Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.19.3). When I run `cat /proc/version_signature` I get the following output: `Ubuntu 4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1-generic 4.2.8-ckt12`.

My understanding of this output is that it is the kernel versions. The last entry there shows a kernel version of 4.2.8-ckt12. Could the issue be that the driver doesn't work well with the kernel version on my machine?

Comment: Hrrrrmmmm.... Can you try a live 16.04 DVD/USB and see where that gets you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the issue had to do with the release of Ubuntu I was running. I followed Android Dev's suggestion of trying 16.04, and after plugging in the dongle, it just worked! Thanks to Android Dev for the suggestion!